# winapi entry point without WinMain

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

So going through a source  of a winapi program I found online I noticed there was no WinMain anywhere, I wonder if is possible in anyway to ever make a winapi program work like this, why do you think the original programmer did anything like this, we have the dialog procedure like this :

```
 static INT_PTR CALLBACK mainDialogProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam,
     LPARAM lParam)
{
 switch(msg)
  {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
   {
    //..............   
   }
  }
}
```

and the main entrypoint was like this instead of void WINAPI WinMain (void);

```
void WINAPI entryPoint(void)
{
 //........
}
```

Is this really possible? it goes against all that I have studied so far...
I'm really sure I'm missing something...

Comment: WinMain is only a convention, you don't *have* to use it.  The linker's /ENTRY option can make any parameter-less function the entrypoint of a program.  Which is rather unwise, you'll bypass the C runtime library initialization.  Not that you'll ever use a lot of it but you'll also bypass any initialization of your own static objects.  Perhaps this was a "smallest possible program" kind of project, using a dialog template is a typical part of such a hack.  Don't do it.

Comment: @HansPassant Furthermore, there are parts of the C runtime that get used implicitly, like /GS buffer overflow protection and `atexit`. So even if you don't think you're using the C runtime, you might be.

Answer (score 7):

The entry point for an executable image is specified through the linker setting [/ENTRY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e.aspx). If not explicitly set, it defaults to `mainCRTStartup` (or `wmainCRTStartup`) for a console application, `WinMainCRTStartup` (or `wWinMainCRTStartup`) for a GUI application, and `_DllMainCRTStartup` for a DLL. When using the CRT that ships as part of Visual Studio, all of the aforementioned raw entry points call into the user-provided entry points `main` (or `wmain`), `WinMain` (or `wWinMain`), and `DllMain`, respectively. This is implemented in *crt0.c* that ships as part of Visual Studio's CRT source code.

If you provide your own entry point (by specifying the `/ENTRY` linker option), it must have the following signature (for a 32-bit application):

```
DWORD CALLBACK RawEntryPoint(void);
```

---

Bonus reading: [WinMain is just the conventional name for the Win32 process entry point](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110525-00/?p=10573)

Comment: Is it required to manually call `ExitProcess()`, or does `return` suffice?

Comment: @bytecode77 If you aren't using the CRT then `return`-ing from the raw entry point will not terminate the process. You will have to call `ExitProcess()` (which is what the CRT is doing for you when you return from the entry point you supply to the CRT to call into). If you don't you'll wind up with a process that continues executing in case there are other threads still running.

Comment: That's what I thought, too. However, reading the process exit code from another application revealed that `return 123` resultet in the corresponding exit code. How can that be? I've disassembled the binary and there is no ExitProcess.

Comment: @bytecode77 The system calls `ExitThread` when the raw entry point returns. If that is the **only** thread in the process, then that terminates the process as well. You *can* get away with not calling `ExitProcess`, but since you aren't in full control over threads that get created in your process, that's all down to hoping for the best.

Comment: Now I get why returning without calling `ExitProcess` works - because there is only one thread in my example. Thank you for your explanation! I've decided to always use ExitProcess to avoid problems later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/ENTRY:"entryPoint"` linker option to set an arbitrary entry point.

Comment: It is an answer only if you already know the answer, and can therefore decipher the text

Comment: By doing that way you will discard all the CLIB and static objects initialization as well as static object destructor ad exception default  catch residing in WinMainCRTStartup that is the default /ENTRY: calling WinMain.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia - we can for example at all not use CRT, or call default CRT entry from entryPoint

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly compiler dependent, but the "entry point" of an executable is a function declared in the linker by means of appropriate options. `WinMainCRTStarup` is just the default, that -after an initialization of the default library- calls `WinMain`.

Anyway, code written like this, is probably defined to be self-contained, with the idea that you will call `enrypoint` from you own `WinMain`, where you can also do anything else.

Comment: `WinMain` never set as default entry point. `WinMainCRTStartup` - usual set as default. `WinMain` is called from  `WinMainCRTStartup`

Comment: @RbMin: Yes, there is some initializatin/termination that happens before: WinMainCRTStartup calls WinMain and mainCRTStartup calls main.

The point is that he can replace them with "entrypoint"" (but missing the startup code) or -much better- call "entripoint" from WinMain, without altering the normal standard initialization sequence.